# Why I get a Error 400 bad request only with datetime

Tags: bad-request

I get a 400 bad request error when the URL send a date time as a parameter expected:

xxx/api/v2/client/64/groups/**2019-01-27T07:07:00**

but if only send a date it works:

xxx/api/v2/client/64/groups/**2019-01-27**

I have tested it on my local envirment and it works with date and datetime parameters, but on the client URL it doesn't work with time. All the configs files are the same both environments. The only difference is the server where it is deployed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the requestPathInvalidCharacters into the web.config.

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,*,\,?"/>
```